# IXMLDOMDocument2 to string javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, msxml

I have a IXMLDOMDocument2 type document. I would like to see the xml for this document. How can I turn it in to a string so I can view it? I am using javascript. The .text properity is just "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
//Convert XML DOM to a string
//for IE 
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var str = myObj.xml;
    alert(str);
 }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
   var str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(myObj);
   alert(str);
}
```

assuming `myObj` is your XML variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let say **d** is your variable for the xml Document

```
var strXML = d.xml; //IE

var strXML = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d); //NON-IE
```